# How to enable hibernate statistics in JHipster?

Tags: hibernate, statistics, jhipster

I tried many things like adding those 2 lines:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE"/>
```

in logback-spring.xml

I also tried to add properties in application-dev.yaml:

```
logging:
    level:
        org.hibernate.type: TRACE
        org.hibernate.stat: DEBUG
        org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql: trace
```

and a combination of some of both but nothing worked!

Notes: i'm a newbie in SpringBoot and also JHipster.
I'm running JHipster 5.7.2 along with SpringBoot 2.0.7

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener" level="DEBUG"/>
```